# Extracting a specific pattern of characters using regular expression

Tags: r, string, gsub

I have the following pattern for a string: `"IGHV1-20*00(1374.6),IGHV1-37*00(1333.7),IGHV1-9*00(752.5)"`. My expected output should look like: `"IGHV1-20,IGHV1-37, IGHV1-9"`.

I'd appreciate any advice on what regex pattern could be defined to extract this output using gsub/str_extract.

Comment: What specific rules do you have? Keep anything that starts with 'IGHV' and has a digit and another two digits after an hyphen? Or rather, delete anything after an asterisks upto comma or end line? It's hard to guess your requirements. If the latter, then `\*[^,]*` replaced with nothing could work.

Comment: Ideally it would be to delete everything after an asterisk up to the comma, as the number of consecutive 'IGHVs' varies (and may follow a different pattern e.g., "IGHK" instead of "IGHV").

Comment: \*[^,]* replaced with nothing works! Thank You very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to match anything that:

1, starts with `IGHV`
2, then a digit followed by '-'
3, one or more digits till the nearest '*'

Try writing a regex with this.